# Swift: App crashes when accessing NULL value from SQLite.swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, sqlite.swift, xcode9.4

i just started learning Swift4. I have read all the suggestions for stack overflow duplicate questions, but I could not solve or understand my problem.

I am fetching Data from a SQLite.swift database:

### ViewController.swift:

```swift
import Foundation
import SQLite

// Load DB with SQLite.swift
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myDataBaseFile", ofType: "sqlite")!
let db = try! Connection(path, readonly: true)

// SQLite.swift define table
let table = Table("table")

// SQLite.swift define columns 
let id = Expression<Int>("id")
let medium = Expression<String>("medium")

// Function to get query result
func queryForMedium(idForQuery: Int) -> String? {
    let media = try? db.scalar(table.select(medium).filter(id == idForQuery))
    return media
}

// ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Value for ID = 2 access a SQL Null value
    anOptionalString = queryForMedium(idForQuery: 2)

    if anOptionalString != nil {
        print("Contains a value!")
    } else {
        print("Doesn’t contain a value.")
    }

}
```

### Result:

- ID = 1 contains "Test" -> App runs:  Console Output: 
   `Contains a value!`
- ID = 2 contains *NULL* -> **CRASH**: Console Output: 
   **`SQLite was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.`**

[image: Xcode Screenshot after App Crash]

Note:
*I have tried to disable Optimazion Level (Build Settings), the result is the same.*

I would be grateful for help or solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell SQLite.swift that the `medium` column can be null by using an optional generic, `<String?>`

Change

```
let medium = Expression<String>("medium")
```

to

```
let medium = Expression<String?>("medium")
```